# Concatenating vars in CouchDB URL rewriting

Tags: couchdb

Some of my CouchDB document ids have a forward slash in them (`/`). I find this problematic for my URLs, because I need to escape them to `%2F`. In rewriting the URLs, I would like to do something like the following

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "from": "/id/:prefix/:postfix",
    "to": "/_show/html/:prefix%2F:postfix",
    "method": "GET",
    "query": {}
  }
]
```

However, this does not lead to my document.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/rewrites.html), CouchDB has supported this kind of rewriting (as stringified functions) since CouchDB 1.7, but [Cloudant's documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/design_documents.html#rewrite-rules) doesn't speak about this particular functionality (only rewrites from arrays).

```
{
  "_id": "_design/myRewrites",
  "rewrites": "function (req2) {\n    return {path: \"../../../\" + req2.path.slice(4).join(\"%2F\")};\n}"
}
```

Rewrite function formatted more nicely:

```
function (req2) {
  return {path: "../../../" + req2.path.slice(4).join("%2F")};
}
```

Note however that [Cloudant does not support rewrites as functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125155/does-cloudant-support-rewrites-as-functions).